# How can I install qTox on (k)ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation, qtox

I tried to compile qTox, but nothing to do.

I tried using [these instructions](https://tox.chat/download.html#gnulinux), but they are only for uTox, not qTox.

Could you help me?

Comment: I successfully compiled and installed qTox on 17.04. I don't think the question is particularly unclear...

Answer (score 5):

#### Easier than installing qTox:

You can install **uTox** trivially using the instructions linked in your question:

```
echo "deb https://pkg.tox.chat/debian stable $(lsb_release -cs)" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list
wget -qO - https://pkg.tox.chat/debian/pkg.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo apt update
sudp apt install utox
```

If you *insist* on using qTox, you can have a go at compiling it. I followed the [installation instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/qTox/qTox/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

### Installing qTox:

The procedure below is what I did to successfully compile and install qTox on Ubuntu MATE 17.04. YMMV, but the instructions are for 16.04 and later.

Install `git` if not already done - we need that to get started

```
sudo apt install git
```

Make a new directory for the sources

```
mkdir $HOME/qTox
cd $HOME/qTox
```

Clone qTox (yes, I know we now have `/home/$USER/qTox/qTox`, there's a reason for this, honest!)

```
git clone https://github.com/qTox/qTox.git qTox
```

Before we try to do anything with that, we need to install the dependencies for it:

```
sudo apt install \
build-essential \
cmake \
libavcodec-dev \
libavdevice-dev \
libavfilter-dev \
libavutil-dev \
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev \
libglib2.0-dev \
libgtk2.0-dev \
libopenal-dev \
libqrencode-dev \
libqt5opengl5-dev \
libqt5svg5-dev \
libsqlcipher-dev \
libswresample-dev \
libswscale-dev \
libxss-dev \
qrencode \
qt5-default \
qt5-qmake \
qttools5-dev-tools
```

We also need to compile `toxcore`, and for that, apparently we need:

```
sudo apt install \
libtool \
autotools-dev \
automake \
checkinstall \
check \
libopus-dev \
libvpx-dev \
libsodium-dev
```

OK we need to clone the `toxcore` repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/toktok/c-toxcore.git toxcore
cd toxcore
```

Notice we are in `/home/$USER/qTox/toxcore`. Tidy, no? :) Continue with:

```
git checkout v0.1.2
autoreconf -if
./configure
```

Now if the `configure` script complains, check that you followed all of the above steps correctly. If you are sure you have installed all the dependencies mentioned, and it complains about a missing library, try... I hate to say "search for the answer", but I'm saying it: try searching in your favourite search engine for the error message, and most likely you will find the answer on Stack Overflow. You can also try `apt search <part-of-library-name>`, but then you have to do some guesswork. In this case I *think* the list of dependencies is complete, so hopefully you will manage. If `./configure` exits successfully, you can run

```
make
```

and if `make` exits successfully, you can run

```
sudo make install
```

(It's a good idea to use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` to create a deb package from the compiled files - then `dpkg` will know about your qtox and will help you to manage it)

```
echo '/usr/local/lib/' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/locallib.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

OK that was `toxcore`, now for qTox, which we're using `cmake` for

```
cd ../qTox     # or if you wandered off:  cd $HOME/qTox/qTox
cmake .        # don't forget the .
make
```

Wait patiently (or admire your amazing CPU if it all happens fast) and when it's done

```
sudo make install
```

(or use `checkinstall`)

And you are done. Run

```
qtox
```

To set up and start using it.

Comment: @Duns awesome to hear that. Hope you enjoy using it :)

Comment: "Easier than installing qTox:" You mean compiling right? I was going to edit, but thought I can ask in comment

Comment: @Anwar well, the question says "how can I install qTox" so I think my wording makes sense, since an annoying compiling process seems to be the way to install qTox. But if I'm wrong and there is a better way, then probably you should add an answer :) And if the wording doesn't make sense to you, feel free to edit it :)

Comment: Oh sorry, Your wording is correct. I missed the "utox" and "qtox" thing and also the user's compilation attemp!

Comment: Use this settings for toxcore:        git clone https://github.com/toktok    /c-toxcore.git toxcore  
    cd toxcore  
    git checkout v0.2.2  
    autoreconf -if  
    ./configure  
    make -j$(nproc)  
    sudo make install  
    echo '/usr/local/lib/' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/locallib.conf  
    sudo ldconfig

Comment: Binary package dist stopped https://blog.tox.chat/2018/02/shutdown-of-the-debian-and-ubuntu-package-repository/